# Improving a stock market algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, stock, yfinance

I am trying to make this code look more attractive for potential employers that view it on my GitHub account. The code essentially loops through a CSV file and searches each symbol with the yfinance wrapper for the Yahoo-Finance API. It makes a few checks about the stock and decides whether it is a suitable investment. There are many try except clauses since API can return empty fields in the pandas dataframe. Currently I think it can be improved since it has multiple nested if statements with many try except statements. All feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import csv
import math
import traceback

# Not a penny stock
# Earnings increase of at least 33% over 10 years using 3 year averages - 10% over 4 years since the API only contains the most recent 4 years
# Current price no more than 1.5x book value per share
# P/E ratio <= 15
# Long term debt no more than 110% current assets
# Current assets 1.5x current liabilities 

symbol_array = []
failed_search = []

with open('companylist.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)

    ticker_data = iter(reader) # skip the first value since it is the header
    next(ticker_data)

    for row in ticker_data:
        ticker = row[0]
        print('Searching: ', ticker)

        try:
            try:
                company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
                company_info = company.info 
            except:
                print('Not a company')
                continue # skip the ticker since it is not a company or the API doesn't have any information about the security

            company_balance_sheet = company.balance_sheet
            company_earnings = company.earnings

            if company_balance_sheet.empty or company_earnings.empty:
                continue # if balance sheets or earnings reports are not available, skip the search

            column_date = company.balance_sheet.columns[0] # latest date on balance sheet to take data from

            current_assets = company.balance_sheet.at['Total Current Assets', column_date]

            try: # previous close price can be under 'previousClose' or 'regularMarketPrice' in company_info
                current_price = company_info['previousClose'] 
            except:
                current_price = company_info['regularMarketPrice']

            if current_price >= 10: # check if stock is penny stock 

                try:
                    long_term_debt = company.balance_sheet.at['Long Term Debt', column_date]
                    if math.isnan(long_term_debt):
                        long_term_debt = 0
                except:
                    long_term_debt=0

                if long_term_debt < (current_assets * 1.1):
                    
                    current_liabilities = company.balance_sheet.at['Total Current Liabilities', column_date]
                    
                    if current_liabilities < (1.5 * current_assets):

                        try:
                            pe_ratio = company_info['trailingPE'] # check if P/E ratio is available, assign pe_ratio 0 if it is not
                        except:
                            pe_ratio = 0


                        if pe_ratio <= 15:

                            try:    
                                book_value = company_info['bookValue']
                                if type(book_value) != float: # book_value can be "None" in the company_info object
                                    book_value = 0
                            except:
                                book_value = 0
                            
                            if current_price < (book_value*1.5):
                                earnings_first = company.earnings.iat[0, 1]
                                earnings_last = company.earnings.iat[len(company.earnings)-1, 1]

                                if earnings_last >= earnings_first*1.1:
                                    symbol_array.append(company_info['symbol'])
                                
                                else:
                                    print('Step 6 fail. Earnings growth too low')

                            else:
                                print('Step 5 fail. Current price too high')

                        else:
                            print('Step 4 fail. P/E ratio too high')

                    else:
                        print('Step 3 fail. Current liabilities too high')

                else:
                    print('Step 2 fail. Long term debt too high')

            else:
                print('Step 1 fail. Penny stock')

        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc()) # code to point out any errors in the main try statement
            failed_search.append(ticker)
            print(ticker, ' failed to search.')
            print(e)

print('Failed searches:')
for failure in failed_search:
    print(failure)

print('Potential Investments:')

for symbol in symbol_array:
    print(symbol)
```

Comment: you asked for feed back ...  1. iterating is an anti-pattern in pandas.  The API supports getting all tickers at once.  then you can check if you received results.  2. `try except:` where you catch every type of exception is bad practice.  If necessary only catch specific exception.  I've been an IT mgr for 20 yrs,  you wouldn't believe the problems I've had to deal with in live systems because programmers have done this. 3. mostly you are using `try except:` as columns vary,  you can test for existence of columns instead of drop into exception handling....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.